# Python subprocess module: How can I pass comma separated input into Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have a list of strings and a command I'd like to run with Popen. The command takes the strings as input arguments.

How can I easily add the entire list...

```
list=['asdf','qwer','zxcv',...]
```

...as comma separated input shown below:

```
Popen(['cmd','asdf','qwer','zxcv',...])
```

I won't be able to do this because it won't convert list to str implicitly:

```
Popen(['cmd',list])
```

Nor this, because it simply won't allow for spaces within a string:

```
Popen(['cmd',' '.join(list)])
```

Is there an alternative?

**I do not want to use the 'shell=True' option.**

Comment: Wouldn't `['cmd'] + list` work perfectly fine here?

Comment: That worked. Didn't know you could do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to create a **new** list from two (or more) separate lists.

```
['cmd'] + list
```

This creates a new list for you with the contents of both. As you mentioned, the syntax looks and does exactly as you expect, which is adding two lists together.

**Note:** I would also like to warn that you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name. Since this means you are shadowing the built-in `list` type. Which could cause unforeseen problems later.